# local npm module "grunt-prettify" not found. is it installed?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, npm-install

I install Node Js and then Grunt. When i run Grunt Copy command, cmd shows these errors:

```
local npm module "grunt-prettify" not found. is it installed?

local npm module "grunt-autoprifixer" not found. is it installed?

local npm module "grunt-contrib-cssmin" not found. is it installed?

local npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. is it installed?
```

Can any one tell me how to get rid of these messages. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `npm install grunt-prettify grunt-autoprifixer grunt-contrib-cssmin grunt-contrib-uglify`